# A proof for the chain rule for paths

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\gamma: I\rightarrow G$ be a differentiable path and $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a real differentiable function. It is to show, that for the path: $f\circ \gamma: I\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ the following formula is true:
>
> $\displaystyle{ (f\ \circ \gamma)'(t) = f_{z}(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)+f_{\overline{z}}(\gamma(t))\overline{\gamma ' (t)}}$
>
> and to conclude that $(f\circ \gamma)'(t)= f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)$.

I began like this:

let $f=u+iv$, it is :  $\displaystyle{f_{x}= u_{x}+iv_{x}, f_{y}=u_{y}+iv_{y}, f_{z}=\frac{1}{2}(f_{x}-if_{y}), f_{z}=\frac{1}{2}(f_{x}-if_{y}), f_{\overline{z}}=\frac{1}{2}(f_{x}+if_{y})}$

then:

$$\begin{align} f \circ \gamma &= f(\gamma(t))= u(x(t),y(t))+iv(x(t),y(t)) \\
(f\ \circ \gamma)'(t) &= u_{x}x'(t)+u_{y}y'(t)+i(v_{x}x'(t)+v_{y}y'(t))\\ &= (u_{x}x'(t)+iv_{x}x'(t))+(u_{y}y'(t)+iv_{y}y'(t))\\
&=f_{x}x'(t) + f_{y}y'(t)
 \end{align}$$

**stuck** .

I don't think this is right so far because I don't see $\overline{\gamma '(t)}$, which should appear. Does anybody see the right way? Please do tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Warning*: "Path integral" means something completely different than what you mean. In fact, I don't even know what you mean, since I don't see any integrals at all.

Terminology aside, to prove the identity, just expand:
\begin{align}
f_z \gamma' + f_{\bar{z}} \bar{\gamma}' &=
\frac{1}{2} (f_x - i f_y)(x' + i y') + \frac{1}{2} (f_x + i f_y) (x'-iy') \\
&=\frac{1}{2}( f_x x' + f_y y' + if_x y' - if_y x' + f_x x' + f_y y' - i f_x y' + i f_y x') \\
&= f_x x' + f_y y',
\end{align}
and you already showed that this last quantity is $(f \circ \gamma)'$.

Comment: Jonathan, Thanks.